# Warning: passing argument x of 'foo' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: pointers, gcc, gcc-warning

So I'm programming in AVR GCC and I've looked around some of the similar questions about this warning and I can't seem to find a clear solution to the matter.

I get this warning when using arrays from a multidimensional array as pointer arguments of a function:

```
// Prototype
int getneighbours (uint8_t *neix[], uint8_t *neiy[], uint8_t nodex, uint8_t nodey);

// Call
uint8_t neighbours[2][4];
getneighbours (&neighbours[X], &neighbours[Y], nodex, nodey);

// Message
expected 'uint8_t **' but argument is of type 'uint8_t (*)[4]'
```

I've been quite afraid of using pointers with multidimensional arrays before, but I really want to know how to avoid getting this warning?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution to my own problem:

```
// Prototype
void getneighbours (uint8_t (*nei)[2][4], uint8_t nodex, uint8_t nodey);

// Call
uint8_t neighbours[2][4];
getneighbours (&neighbours, nodex, nodey);
```

So for people having the same issue, this would be how you properly handle multidimensional array pointers.